# Adding time in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am working with mongodb & mongoose and I want to basically get the sum of two properties.

The Json data consists of some tasks along with their time taken for different users. Here name property indicates the task names for a single user.
I want the sum of the data.timer property in the totalTime property, for each mail Id.
It would be nice if the sum is then converted to mins. (like 120mins or 55mins for example)

If the addition of timer property is not possible then the sum of time of data.date (Task end time) and data.start(Task start time) is also okay. How can I achieve this?

```
[
  {
      "_id": "sam@gmail.com",
      "taskCount": 6,
      "totalTime": 0,
      "data": [
          {
              "username": "sam",
              "email": "sam@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": true,
              "name": "First",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 07:22:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:09",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 07:22:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          },
          {
              "username": "sam",
              "email": "sam@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": true,
              "name": "Second",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 07:22:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:18",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 07:22:35 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          },
          {
              "username": "sam",
              "email": "sam@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": true,
              "name": "Next Task",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:36:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:07",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:36:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          },
          {
              "username": "sam",
              "email": "sam@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": true,
              "name": "dfg",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:49:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:08",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:48:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          },
          {
              "username": "sam",
              "email": "sam@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": true,
              "name": "dfgdf",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:49:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:02",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:49:43 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          },
          {
              "username": "sam",
              "email": "sam@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": true,
              "name": "dfg",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:51:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:02",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 08:51:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "_id": "honda@gmail.com",
      "taskCount": 1,
      "totalTime": 0,
      "data": [
          {
              "username": "vksam",
              "email": "honda@gmail.com",
              "isAdmin": false,
              "name": "honnda",
              "date": "Fri Sep 30 2022 07:23:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
              "timer": "00:00:10",
              "start": "Fri Sep 30 2022 07:23:19 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the json data to a const variable and use 'Map Function' to achieve this.

Research on `npm install timelite`
or follow the [link](https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/dc205abcc9733630639eaf43e267d63f)

and lemme know whether it works :)